Server is trying to connect to mail servers i dont know of
When inspecting /var/log/auth.log i see a lot of these errors:
error: connect_to imap.tele2.nl port 993: failed.
error: connect_to mail.spraytech: unknown host (Name or service not known)
error: connect_to mail.kefgames.net port 110: failed.
error: connect_to mail.fuse.net port 993: failed.

I never configured any of these domains/servers.
I already tried searching online how to find out what starts these connections. I have not found anything. I am hoping to find out what causes these connections and how to block or stop sending them.

Usually auth.log also shows which application generates the events. That might explain what they are and how they come about. - Those port numbers are POP3 and IMAP so when you’re offering for example webmail, that installation might also allow your users to (attempt to) manage mail from other mailboxes rather than exclusively the ones you offer them … Others reasons are of course possible too

the process seems to be sshd. I am the only user on this server and do not use mail on that server.
